# Send to messenger not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to add facebook's "`send to messenger`" to my web page.

On Fb's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#send_to_messenger_plugin) it states:

> When there isn't an active session, no identity is surfaced. When the
>   button is clicked, we will present a Login dialog.

[image]

But what I realize is that if a user is not logged in to facebook the button doesn't get rendered at all.
Is this the expected behaviour?

PS- Note that my fb app is not in dev mode and I'm using the a fb account with admin role for that app.

Answer (score 6):

If you app has not yet been reviewed, the login dialog and button only appear for individuals with certain roles - admin, developer, tester, and insight users.

Also it can take a few moments to load.

Comment: that's what I've read on the documentation but...I'm an admin and I still can't see it. Does the app have to be fully reviewed and live for the send to messenger to show up when there is no active fb session?

Comment: No it shouldn't have to be. Are you able to see it with an active FB session?

Comment: yes. if I have a fb session the button gets rendered.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is the expected behaviour.

As mentioned in the FB [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#send_to_messenger_plugin):

> When your app is in development mode, or if your app is public but
>   does not have approval for Messenger platform, the plugin is only
>   visible to admins, developers and testers of the app. **Therefore, the
>   plugin will not be visible when there isn't an active session since
>   the user cannot be identified.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm admin of an app which has never been submitted for review. The app was up a while ago and for some reasons I had to do this again:

- in your app Messenger settings > **Token Generation** select your page, generate a token,
- in your app Messenger settings > **Webhooks** make sure your page is subscribed to webhooks,
- in your code or environment variables, update your token and deploy the changes.